# Prevent array re-shuffle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been creating a Q&A app in SwiftUI and have been trying to make an array for the answers which is shuffled. Originally I shuffled the array as follows:

```swift
var answers = ["answerOne", "answerTwo", "answerThree", "answerfour"].shuffled
```

This array was displayed on screen in a `ForEach` loop which provided the choices (answers that can be selected) in a column as shown below:

```
Question:
Answer One
Answer Two
Answer Three
Answer Four

(Check answer button)
```

Whilst this worked very well, when the check answer button was pressed, the answer array would once again shuffle to a different order as shown below, which is not desirable.

```
Question:
Answer Three
Answer One
Answer Two
Answer Four

(Next question button)
```

Is there a way I can shuffle the array only when the "next question button" is pressed and not the "check answer button"?

Below is the code I have tried as a solution but it doesn't seem to be working out and I would really appreciate any input or ideas anyone has!

```swift
Button(action: {
    if(oddEven % 2 == 0) {
        checkNextText = "Next"
        oddEven += 1
    } else {
        checkNextText = "Check"
        answers.shuffled()
        oddEven += 1
    }
```

Note: `checkNextText` is the text for the button at the bottom of the screen, `oddEven` is a Int variable to determine whether the button should read check or next.

Minimal reproduction code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var oddEven = 0
    @State var checkNextText = "Check"
    
    var body: some View {

        var orderedAnswers = [                    
        "answerOne",
        "answerTwo",
        "answerThree",
        "answerFour"                    
        ].shuffled()

        Text("Question One")

        ForEach(0..<4) { number in
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text(orderedAnswers[number])
                })
        }

        Button(action: {
            if(oddEven % 2 == 0) {
                checkNextText = "Next"
                oddEven += 1            
            } else {
                checkNextText = "Check"
                oddEven += 1
            }
        }, label: {                        
            Text(checkNextText)
        })    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre] that someone can copy and paste into Xcode to see what you have so far?

Comment: Hi! No problem, I will add one in the edit.

Comment: The `body` is refreshed every time something in your view changes... so since `var orderedAnswers = [` is inside the `body`, it will reshuffle unexpectedly. Move it outside.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @aheze. The only issue is that the code I have provided is a very cut-down version of the actual code and moving it outside the body would require a lot of reconstructing. Is there any other way to achieve the shuffling without having to move the array outside the body?

Comment: @imjonu unfortunately not. Usually you want all your variables to be outside the body, otherwise you’ll run into weird side effects.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, the idiomatic approach is to store the array within your View, not as a local variable within the `body` property, because, as already pointed out, you get a new shuffle each time `body` is called (which is likely to happen more than once).

However, if for various reasons you cannot extract the code outside of the body, one alternative would be to use a `@State` property that gets set only once:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State orderedAnswers: [String]?
```

, and do the computation only if the state is not set:

```swift
var body: some View {
    var orderedAnswers = self.orderedAnswers ?? [                    
        "answerOne",
        "answerTwo",
        "answerThree",
        "answerFour"                    
        ].shuffled()
```